# How do i install virtualbox-guest-additions on fedora silverblue

Tags: command-line, fedora, terminal, virtualbox

I recently installed Fedora Silverblue on Virtualbox. I tried to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions but it always fails. First, I tried:

`sudo rpm-ostree install virtualbox-guest-additions`

But I got:

`error: "virtualbox-guest-additions" is already provided by: virtualbox-guest-
 additions-6.0.4-2.fc30.x86_64. Use --allow-inactive to explicitly require it.`

The system says that the Virtualbox Guest Additions are already installed but it does not work.
After that, I tried installing it via the ISO image but it does not work too because it is a read file system which I understand.

So, does anyone know how to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions on Fedora Silverblue?

EDIT:

`sudo modprobe -v vboxvideo` gives me:

```
insmod /lib/modules/5.3.15-300.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_vram_helper.ko.xz
insmod /lib/modules/5.3.15-300.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko.xz
```

And this is the output for `modinfo vboxguest`:

```
filename:        /lib/modules/5.3.15-300.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/virt/vboxguest/vboxguest.ko.xz
license:          GPL
description:      Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
author:           Oracle Corporation
alias:            pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc⋆sc⋆i⋆
depends:                                                                 
retpoline:        Y
intree:           Y
name:             vboxguest
vermagic:         5.3.15-300.fc31.x86_64 SMP mod_unload
sig_id:           PKCS#7
signer:           Fedora kernel signing key
```

Comment: "but it does not work" ... What are the symptoms?

Comment: When I try to install the ISO, I get the message that the virtualbox guest additions are already installed. Instead I should update or remove the guest additions but I do not know how. I tried to install it anyway but I always got the message `read-only file system`.

Comment: "The system says that the Virtualbox Guest Additions are already installed..."   Why do you think that is false?

Comment: Because I cannot use the features of the guest additions like better performance.

Comment: What's the output of `lsmod | grep vbox`?

Comment: The output is `vboxguest         45056   4`.

Comment: Interesting.  No `vboxsf` nor `vboxvideo`.  Does `modprobe -v vboxvideo` work?  Does `modinfo vboxguest` show the correct version for your VirtualBox?

Comment: I wrote the output in the question.

Comment: It looks like you have the kernel modules, they just weren't loaded.  After all the kernel modules are loaded, does everything work for you?

Comment: No, even though the kernel modules are already loaded.

Comment: So, after all the kernel modules are loaded, what features are you missing?  I.e., what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Is your purpose to set full resolution for Silverblue running under Virtualbox? If so, try to set the resolution manually using Gnome settings (Settings->Devices->Displays->Resolution). Worked for me.

Comment: The OP didn't/doesn't seem to have all the VirtualBox kernel modules loaded while running SilverBlue.  Which VirtualBox kernel modules do you have loaded?

Comment: Mine is default install of Silverblue. When I search 'lsmod' for vbox I only get 'vboxguest'. The 'modinfo vboxguest' command gives me almost same output except my kernel is 5.3.16 (5.3.16-300.fc31.x86_64), whereas OP's is 5.3.15 (5.3.15-300.fc31.x86_64).

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder why SilverBlue doesn't load the other vbox kernel modules.  If you `modprobe -v vboxvideo` and `modprobe -v vboxsf`, do you get all the vbox guest features?

Comment: Do we need them? My resolution working find with just vboxguest. Anyways, for 'modprobe -v vboxvideo' I get same output as OP's and for 'modprobe -v vboxsf', I get 'Module vboxsf not found in ..." error.

Comment: "Do we need them? "  I suppose that's up to each user to decide.  The OP wanted vbox kernel modules for reasons unclear to me.